# Calculate $\phi(36)$, where $\phi$ is the Euler Totient function. Use this to calculate $13788 \pmod {36}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

I am wondering if anyone can help me. I am trying to figure out how to

> Calculate $\phi(36)$, where $\phi$ is the Euler Totient function. Use this to calculate $13788 \pmod {36}$.

I have an exam coming up an this will be one style of question. Can anyone please walk me through how it is done?

Thanks to SchrodingersCat I now know first part is $12$.

The second part should be along the lines of below but I do not understand how this was arrived at.
\begin{align}
13788 \pmod {36} &= 13788 \pmod {\phi(36)} \pmod {36} \\ &= 13788 \pmod {12} \pmod {36} \\ &= 138 \pmod {36} \\ &= ((132)2)2 \pmod {36} \\ &= (252)2 \pmod {36} \\ &= 132 \pmod {36} \\ &= 25
\end{align}

Can anyone show me why it is $25$ and how do I get it?

Comment: Hint: the totient function is multiplicative. That is $\phi(ab) = \phi(a)\phi(b)$.

Comment: Was the question to calculate 13788 mod 36.  Or to calculate $b^{13788} \mod 36$ for $b = $ some odd number not divisible by 3?

Answer (score 3):

$36=4\times9$

Since $4$ and $9$ are relatively prime, we have

$\phi(36)=\phi(4)\phi(9)$

Using the identity that for any prime $p$,  $\phi(p^n)=p^n-p^{n-1}$

$\phi(4)\phi(9)=\phi(2^2)\phi(3^2)=(2^2-2).(3^2-3)=12$

As for the second part of the question, then, 13788 (mod 12) (mod 36) $\ne
138(mod 36)$ and hence your question is wrong.

There seems to be typo error and this part of the question can be modified to $13^{788}(mod\ 36) = 13^{788(mod \phi(36))}(mod\ 36) = 13^{788(mod 12)}(mod\ 36)=13^8(mod\  36)=25$

Answer (score 2):

$$36=2^2\cdot 3^2$$

So $$\phi(36)=36\cdot \left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left( 1-\frac{1}{3}\right)=12$$

If you are unaware of this formula, then check this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Proof_of_Euler.27s_product_formula) and also the example there.

For the second part, observe that $13788=2^2\cdot 3^2\cdot 383$

So $36$ divides $13788$.

That is, $$13788 \equiv 0 \pmod {36}$$

Comment: Reason for the downvoting??

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you didn't explain how tortient(36) =12 implies 36 divides 13788.  You just did it.

Comment: ... but then I can't figure it out either.

Comment: The answer for the second part is: 13788 (mod 36) = 13788 (mod φ(36)) (mod 36) = 13788 (mod 12) (mod 36) = 138
(mod 36) =((132)2)2(mod 36) = (252)2(mod 36) = 132(mod 36) = 25, but I can not figure out how this answer was achieved

Answer (score 1):

Remember that:

$\phi(p)=p-1$

$\phi(p^n) = p^n -p^{n-1}$

for every prime number $p$.

And $\phi(ab)=\phi(a)\phi(b)$ whenever $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime.

Thus $\phi(36) = \phi(9)\phi(4)=\phi(3^2)\phi(2^2)=(9-3)(4-2)=12$.

We are lucky since

$13788 = 383\cdot 36$

and so

$13788 = 383\cdot 36 \equiv 0 \pmod{36}$.

If you want to compute $a^{13788}$ modulo $36$ when $a$ and $36$ are relatively prime, you can use Little Fermat Theorem which says that

$a^{\phi(36)} \equiv 1 \pmod{36}$.

You get

$a^{13788} = (a^{12})^{1149} \equiv 1^{1149} \equiv 1 \pmod{36}$.

Comment: I added the last part, the request to calculate the last part is really frequent and much more related to the $\phi$ function!

Comment: Except it doesn't tell us how to calculate 13788 mod 36 ... which I admit, the relevence of the tortient function is escaping me. I thought maybe 13789 was the twelvth root of something but ... no.

Comment: In fact, asking for a power of 13788 is much more interesting.

Comment: I wonder if the question was to calculate $5^{13788} \mod 36$. Showing 36|13788 is pretty simple.

Comment: Yes, probably this is the case!